# SSRS: Is it possible to repeat a row in ssrs without it being a Header?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I'm currently trying to get a row to repeat every page without it being a header. Due to the row being a parent to the rest of the data, I can't seem to use that as a header.

Answer (score 0):

Go into the Group Details area at the bottom, open up Advanced Mode by clicking the down arrow at the top left of the Group Details area. Then choose the group (most likely going to be '(static)', go to the properties tab, and put "True" for the "RepeatOnNewPage" area.